# How to install Windows 10 32 bit in Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit parallel?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit in my laptop. Now I want to install Windows 10 32 bit parallel. If it's possible then how to do it? My system configuration is 500 GB hard disk and 4 GB RAM.

Comment: that means I have to install 64 bit window?

Comment: This is April 2018.  Everything should always be 64 bit.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal You had originally tagged this [tag:14.04] but in the body of the post you say it's a 16.04 system. Does this relate to 14.04 in any way? If so, please **[edit]** to clarify (in which case you could also add back that tag).